# cp210x on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb

I am trying to install cp210x driver on ubuntu 18.04.2 and when I download the file from the official website of silabs and try to install it by following the instructions I get this error on my first step.

After I type *make* :

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/$user/linuxDrv modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
 Building modules, stage 2.
 MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
```

I installed libelf-dev but not the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Happily, the cp210x kernel module (driver) is already included in Ubuntu. You don't need to compile it.

1) Check your kernel version.

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-20-generic
```

2) Check that you have the correct package installed for your kernel.

```
$ apt list linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-20-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-20-generic/disco-updates,disco-security,now 5.0.0-20.21 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

See how the kernel version is part of the package name?
And see how it's installed on my machine?

3) Let's verify that the module is included in this installed package.

```
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-20-generic | grep cp210x
/lib/modules/5.0.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
```

4) Finally, let's install the kernel module (driver):

```
$ sudo modprobe cp210x
$
```

Note that no feedback usually indicates success. It's a good thing.

To check that it worked, use the `lsmod` command to list all loaded kernel modules.

---

If, for whatever reason, Step 2 indicates that you DON'T have the package installed, read this wisdom from the package's control file before racing to install it:

> You likely do not want to install this package directly. Instead,
>   install  the linux-generic meta-package, which will ensure that
>   upgrades work  correctly, and that supporting packages are also
>   installed.

Comment: Thank your for answering. I have a match on my cp210x.ko file so that means it is there. When I try your last command (sudo modprobe cp210x) I dont get any output so does that mean that it is installed on my kernel?

Comment: I found it thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lsmod | grep cp210x
```

Should return what you're looking for. Namely :

```
cp210x                 40960  1
usbserial              57344  3 cp210x
```